# ServerInterceptor lifecycle for a bidirectional streaming API

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have `ServerInterceptor` implementation as follows:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
            final Metadata headers,
            final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
  
  System.out.println("Call started");

  return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, headers)) {
    public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
      System.out.println("onMessage");
      super.onMessage(message);
    }

    public void onCancel() {
      System.out.println("onCancel");
      super.onCancel();
    }

    public void onComplete() {
      System.out.println("onComplete");
      super.onComplete();
    };
  }
}
```

I am expecting that for a bidirectional streaming API call, I'll see one "Call Started", multiple "onMessage" (depending on the number of requests in the stream) and one of either "onComplete" or "onCancel".

Similarly for unary API call, I am expecting one each of "Call Started", "onMessage" and "onComplete/onCancel" per call.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.
The event order of method you can reference this picture:
[image]

You can read this note for more detail: https://helloworlde.github.io/2021/02/20/gRPC-%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E9%97%B4%E8%B0%83%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B/

Comment: Thanks for the picture! If I want to reject a streaming call, should I call `serverCall.Close()` or simply return an empty `ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {}`? If I close the serverCall, will subsequent request from the same client be allowed or will the channel be closed for all requests being multiplexed on this channel?

Comment: @amitsaurav Call `StreamObserver#onCompleted` could be better rather than `ServerCall#close` to stop the stream. `ServerCall.Listener` is just a listener, it can't operate request. The subsequent request will cancelled because the stream is closed or completed. Channel won't be efected even request failed.